# What’s the “elevator pitch” for our site?

Tags: discussion, 7-questions

From the [The 7 Essential Meta Questions of Every Beta](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/the-7-essential-meta-questions-of-every-beta/):

---

### What’s the “elevator pitch” for our site?

Imagine you’ve just gotten on an elevator with a friendly stranger. You have precisely one floor to describe your community to them. What would you say? The elevator pitch is a brief sentence that describes *what your site is about*. Every word counts!

Once decided, it can be sliced and diced to form:

- the tagline
- the motto
- the blurb under the logo
- a convenience redirect “nickname” for the site
- perhaps eventually the domain name [in some form](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/domain-names/)

(Due to a variety of [practical difficulties with domain names](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/10/domain-names-the-wrong-question/), we prefer to de-emphasize domain name selection. Most sites will retain their `topic.stackexchange.com` names indefinitely.)

Naming is hard — *really* hard. But if you can come up with a sensible elevator pitch for your community, it’s a great starting point.

For more detail see: [Stack Exchange Naming for Dummies](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/10/stack-exchange-naming-for-dummies/)